# I want to use path value from views.py to django template html

Tags: python, django

**VIEWS.PY CODE**
`data = { "product" : { "product1":{ "path":"assets/carouselImgs/laptop1.png" }, } }`

I want to use this path value to load image.

**HTML CODE**
`<img class="carousel-img" src="{% static 'how can i use path value here' %}" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this inside your template's HTML:

```html
<img 
class="carousel-img" 
src="{% static product.product1.path %}" 
alt="">
```

---

**Side Note:** If you have multiple products (e.g. product1, product2, etc.), consider using a list of dictionaries and a for loop instead of nested dictionaries, e.g.:

```py
products = [   # rename 'data' to 'products'
    {
        "name": "product1", 
        "path": "assets/carouselImgs/laptop1.png",
    }, {
        "name": "product2", 
        "path": "assets/carouselImgs/laptop2.png",
    },
]
```

Then in your HTML you can do the following:

```
{% for product in products %}
<div>
  <img 
  class="carousel-img" 
  src="{% static product.path %}" 
  alt="">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```